# How to update a procedure in another form's subform?

Tags: database, forms, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form (MainForm) with 2 subforms, sfrmA & sfrmB. I need to call a procedure (ProcInB) in sfrmB from sfrmA . None of these work:

```
Forms!MainForm.sfrmB.Form.ProcInB
Call MainForm.Forms.sfrmB.ProcInB
Forms!MainForm![sfrmB].Form.ProcInB
Call MainForm.Forms.sfrmB.ProcInB
Call Forms.MainForm.ProcInB
```

I've also tried parentheses, quotes, etc. Nothing seems to work and an exhaustive search hasn't provided this specific situation or solution.

Hope someone has the answer!

Thx!

Comment: Is `ProcInB` defined as `Public`? ... like `Public Sub ProcInB()`

Comment: In the Immediate window, what does `Debug.Print Forms!MainForm!sfrmB.Form.Name` give you?

Comment: Error message: can't find sfrmB

Comment: Good, thanks.  So `sfrmB` is the name of a form.  And it is used in a subform control of a form named `MainForm`.  If both those statements are true, what is the name of the subform control on `MainForm` which contains `sfrmB`?

Comment: Main Form is called MainForm.
Subform A in MainForm is called sfrmA.
Subform B in MainForm is called sfrmB.
Subform B (sfrmB) contains a public procedure (ProcInB) that does something.
Subform A (sfrmA) is trying to call the public procedure (ProcInB) in Subform B (sfrmB).

Answer (score 1):

To call a procedure in a form (or any class) module, you do

```
Call Form_sfrmB.ProcInB()
```

Of course ProcInB() must be declared as **Public**.

`Form_<name>` is how form class modules are named, you see it in the VBA project explorer.

It doesn't matter if the form is a subform in another form. The syntax variations you tried are for accessing **controls** on subforms, not functions.

Comment: It is possible to call a public procedure in a form via the open form instance instead of via the form's module.  For example `Forms!frmStart.demo_combos` calls the procedure in that form without error.

Comment: You're right (as usual). For me it feels ... odd, though. And the fact that `Call Forms!frmStart.demo_combos` fails (compile error) doesn't help to mitigate that feeling. @HansUp

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. The procedure/subroutine gives back the error message "Object Required". The subroutine was public, but I even changed it to a public function to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't.

Comment: @Andre451  Interesting.  I don't understand why it triggers a compile error with `Call`.  But I seldom use `Call`.  Calling it with just `Forms!frmStart.Demo_combos` compiles without error for me.

Comment: And "Forms!frmStart.demo_combos" can't find the form.

Comment: @monbois: Is the error actually in the `Call Form_sfrmB.ProcInB()` line, not inside of `ProcInB`? --- If it is the call, are you sure you have `Form_sfrmB` right? (I assume sfrmB is not the real name). Perhaps post a bit of code.

Comment: Andre451 - Thanks for your feedback, but you're mistaken. I already use the following syntax to call a public subroutine in the Main Form (MainForm) from subform A (sfrmA): Call Forms.MainForm.PublicProcInMainForm.

Naturally this was the first one I tried, but it can't find subform B on the Main Form.

Comment: @monbois: I'm not talking about `Forms.sfrmB.ProcInB` but  `Form_sfrmB.ProcInB` .